# Text underneath text input

Tags: css

I have this css http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/3GYY4/ and beneath each text input,i want to have some text which i can use to have some guiding text about that text input like

[image]

My current html and css looks like this

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<title>Lorem ipsum text below form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.zseform{
width:300px;
background-color:#E6E6FA;
}
label{
width:15%;
float:left;
}
p{
background-color:#B0C4DE;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<label>Logo</label><input class="zseform" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
<label>City</label><input class="zseform" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
<label>Address</label><input class="zseform" type="text" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, just use the `placeholder` attribute, and a [polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to make it work in older browsers.

Comment: Actually underneath each input or inside the input?

Comment: Its underneath,i have corrected the title.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3GYY4/3/

Comment: Yes,that has worked.Could you please add that as an answer?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as placing an element after the input, setting is as `display:block` and setting the padding. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3GYY4/3/).

Comment: I was writing answer too, but You were firts, and my solution isn't very different than yours. So I post a commend (I see no point for posting such similar answer). 

My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/3GYY4/

Comment: You might want to check your link. It seems to point to the original code.

Comment: Yeah. Not much difference really. You actually clear the left float though which is probably better. There's so many ways to do it though.